# Could not find method configFailurePolicy() for arguments [continue] on org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions_Decorated@ae0471c

Tags: java, maven, gradle, testng

I want to set `configfailurepolicy = continue` in `testng` because whenever the `@before` or `@after` class fails the tests after that are getting skipped. Do I need to make any changes in the `testng` as well?

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
defaultTasks = ['deploy']
/*
 * Task to generate Gradle Wrapper artifacts. This is
 * only required to update the wrapper itself and not
 * needed for regular builds.
 */

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
    distributionUrl = "http://services.gradle.org/
                       distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip"
}

test {
    useTestNG() {
        configFailurePolicy 'continue'
        // includeGroups 'myTestGroup'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://x.x.x.x:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```

Comment: I shifted the body of the question above the code block. Try to describe the problem before pasting a long piece of code - it makes things clearer. Also, try to use formatting to clearly mark up your question, and see if you can shorten the title to make it more concise.

Comment: It looks you are not using Gradle 2.3 binaries (even if you have it in build.gradle) which command you are using for test run? And what is output for `gradlew -version`?

Comment: The gradlew -v shows 2.3. When i comment that 'configfailurepolicy' build will work fine.

Comment: @Jaroslav Well, that issue is fixed when i rebuilt the wrapper. But still whenever the `beforeClass` or `AfterClass` method fails the successive tests are getting skipped. Do i need to make any changes in the testng as well ?

Comment: No, you don't need to change anything in TestNG. What version of TestNG you use (this option was also added later)? I don't see dependencies section in build.gradle file.